# Tensorflow 2: shape mismatch when serialize and decode it back

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor A of shape (300,256,256).
I want to serialize A to save as tfrecord format.
But I cannot convert it back to tensor with same shape.

```
A = tf.convert_to_tensor( *a numpy array with float32 type* )
B = tf.io.serialize_tensor(A)
C = tf.reshape(tf.io.decode_raw(B, out_type=tf.float32),[300,256,256])
```

If I run the code above, I got a shape error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 19660806 values, but the requested shape has 19660800 [Op:Reshape]

It seems that when I serialize or when I decode, 6 floats are added. (very weird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using: `tf.io.parse_tensor()`, instead of `tf.io.decode_raw()`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_tensor

Comment: Thanks. When using tf.io.parse_tensor() found out that we don't need to reshape it.